# Plot with variable background color

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm plotting line charts with the x-axis representing the timeline. Some of the dataranges should be marked as unreliable. For showig this it would be great to change the background color over these x-ranges to some bringt yellow or red. Is there an option of doing that?

I know that could us gscatter instead of gplot for using colors. But then only the data is colored and not the background and I don't get linecharts but point charts. Colored data would be an acceptable alternative, but I need line charts.

Answer (score 1):

It is always possible to make a filled polygon plot. Try,

```
a = 0:0.1:1;
b = a;
figure;
plot(a,b,'r');
hold on;
x = [0 0 1 1 0];
y = [0 1 1 0 0];
h = fill(x,y,'g');
set(h,'FaceAlpha',0.1); % or alpha(h,0.1); would also work
```

Comment: Ok, that nearly solves it. The problem is that I don't know how big the y-values might get. Is it somehow possible that the graph still fits to the data and the polygones detect the height of the graph and fill the window completely? I don't want to use ylim.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, can you not set the range of polygons to the range of the plotted graphs? Also even it is not an answer to your comment, note that you can plot multiple polygons as well.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how the y-range of the plotted graph will be. Of course I could loop through all the data to plot in order to find the maximum and then fix the graph to this max with ylim and use this y value also for the polygon. But this is what I want to avoid as described above. And I can't just set the y-limits of the polygon arbitrary high because the graph scale will then fit to the polygon and not the data anymore.

Comment: There are no way to do this if you want to have more than one color, and you cannot set alpha channel either. Note however that it is possible to set `xlim` and `ylim` if you want. Also I do not know why you do not know your range. you can plot the polygons last and then you should know all your data values. Or are you doing this recursively?

Comment: Ok, good to know. But as I wrote in both comments I want to avoid ylim. And as described I could get the range by computing the maximum of the whole dataset which I wanted to avoid - if I would do that I could also use ylim.

Comment: Now I am really curious, you plot all the data and do not use recursive formulas. This means that you have already looped through the data once. Why can you just not do a minmax of every dataset the same time as you loop through it to plot and save the values. Compared to the plotting, this will barely slow your runtime. Then plot the polygons when everything is correct. Even if you use a recursive formula you can still save the min and max. This does only requires to remember 2 doubles and should require minimum effort and memory.